# Not able to update the array state in a async Promise call inside on a upload image in react application using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload **multiple** **images** on Firebase and get the URLs of each image and push them onto the database using api calls *(With redux)*. I am trying to implement it using `Promise.all()` but the urls are being fetched asyncronously and the `Promise.all()` call is executed before the array state gets updated. Here is the code that might help you understand better.

```
.......... 
const [imgs,setImgs] = useState([])
const [urls,setUrls] = useState([]);
..........

//Code for setImg that will add all the files that are been selected!
..........

const uploadImages = async () => {
    const promises = [];
    imgs.map((image) => {
      const imageRef = ref(storage, `Drives/${image.name + v4()}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
      promises.push(uploadTask);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const progress = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          // dispatch(fetchStart());
        },
        (error) => {
          alert(error);
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
            console.log(url); // this is been shown after the promise.all is executed!!
            setUrls((oldArray) => [...oldArray, url]); // This is not getting updated as expexted!!
          });
        }
      );
    });

    Promise.all(promises) // Being executed before the urls state is updated hence is submitting a empty array!!
      .then(() => {
        toast.success("All images uploaded");
        const FormatDate = moment(data.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        const { __v, ...rest } = data;
        if (urls.length === 0) {
          toast.error("Urls were not Pushed!!");
          console.log(urls);
          dispatch(clearState());
          return 0;
        }
        const formData = {
          ...rest,
          date: FormatDate,
          driveImages: [...urls] ,// Or urls ---- This is showing empty.. But after some time urls is being updated!!
          flags: {
            isUploadImage: true,
          },
        };
        dispatch(updateDrives(formData));
      })
      .catch((err) => toast.error(err));
  };
```

I have mentioned appropriate comments in the code for better understanding.

The versions of firebase that I am using is `"firebase": "^9.7.0"`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, there are some key points to check in your code:

1. Have you put `uploadImages()` function in a `useEffect` with a dependency of `imgs` to make sure `imgs` is not empty itself and the function will get called when imgs gets updated?

   ```
     useEffect(()=>{uploadImages()},[imgs]);
   ```
2. When it comes to promises, keep in mind that there are two general approaches: using `async/await` or `then()/catch()`. Use one approach. If you are using `async`, you should use `await` before calling functions returning a promise.
3. map() function in js always should return a result in each iteration. If you don't return anything all you get is an array with undefined values no matter what you have done in each iteration.

   ```
    const promiseArray = imgs.map(async () => {
    try{
      const uploadTask = await uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image);
      ...
      return uploadTask;
       } catch(err){ 
         // handle err
       };
   });

   const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
   ```

If you don't want to return a value, use `forEach()` instead.

Comment: Hey!! I have called the `uploadImages` on a Button Press. And the button only shows if `imgs` has something in it still there seems to be an issue in the map and `uploadTask.on`!!
I did try the async await approach, In this approach, I don't get the function `uploadTask.on` and won't be able to get the **url**